# transform.position not returning the good position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform

I made a code that tell me how many positions can the player see on a 2D map.
When I test the code by moving all around the map and testing differents position, it's working. The next step was to create a heatmap of the numbers of position the player can see for every positions. But when I try to run the code, it return false positions.

I've tried different local and global transform methods, and it didn't work

```
void HtPnt (Vector2 g)
{
    int pnt = 0;
    foreach (Vector2 f in Q)
    {
        bool compt = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < criticalPointDebug.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (IsInsideTriangle(f, g, criticalPointDebug[i].location, criticalPointDebug[i + 1].location))
                compt = true;
        }
        if (compt == true)
            pnt += 1;
    }
}
```

// criticalPointDebug is the list of the visibility polygon, and here's my test in update() :

```
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
                {
                    for (int x=0;x<5;x++)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(position);
                        transform.position = new Vector2(5 + .5f * x, 4);
                        HtPnt(position);
                        Debug.Log(position);
                    }
                 }
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
                {
                    Debug.Log(position);
                    transform.position = new Vector2(5,4);
                    position = new Vector2(5, 4);
                    HtPnt(position);
                    Debug.Log(position);
                }
```

first test is returning the correct value of the position on the player (before runing the test) 5 times and the second return nonsense result. Thanks in advance for enlighting me on my problem !

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. There's not enough information to reproduce the problem statement, so it's hard to determine the cause of the problem. Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58608231/edit) so that it includes a [mre].

Comment: By first test I assume you mean when pressing `A`? You are giving it different positions there. Also you change the `transform.position` but never change the `position` variable value in the first case .. only in the second where you set it fixed to `5, 4`...